# Change dropdown selected value in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am looping through available appointments and trying to change the color of the selected value in the dropdown(more than 1 dropdown in the list). I can see the color is different for each value but when I select it changes it back to black.

```css
    .appt-status select option[value="0"] {
        color: #3EA47B;
    }

    .appt-status option[value="1"] {
        color: #3EA47B
    }

    .appt-status option[value="2"] {
        color: #FF0000;
    }

    .appt-status option[value="3"] {
        color: #FFA927;
    }
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

 <div class="appointmentList" data-bind="foreach: visibleAppointments">
      <select class="form-control appt-status" data-bind="value: confirmationStatus, event:{ change: $parent.statusChanged}" >
                    <option data-icon="" class="status-list" value="1" > Confirmed</option>
                    <option class="status-list" value="2" >Reschedule</option>
                    <option class="status-list" value="3" >Pending</option>
                    <option class="status-list" value="0" >Not opted-in</option>
                </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: To do exactly what you want with select html, you need to use js

Comment: This will solve my issue. Thank you @SKJ